# Div automatically closing as generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, append

I have a problem with my div generation, as I generate a form I want to wrap them in a div with same id. But when I inspect the element it's automatically closing before the form. So it doesn't wrap around it as surpose to, it just `<div></div>` above the form.

```
var startDiv = "<div id='appm'>";
var endDiv = "</div>";

for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 8){   

    $('#youEvents').append(     

        $('<form />', { id: values[i], method: 'POST' }).append(
            startDiv, // Starting div id=appm
            $('<textarea />', { id: "teast", name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i + 1], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i + 2], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: "ee", placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i + 3], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder1: 'Name', value: values[i + 4], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i + 5], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'address', id: 'rdescription', name: 'heya', value: values[i + 6], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),
            $('<input />', { id: 'adress', name: 'routetags', placeholder: 'tags', value: values[i + 7], type: 'text' }),
            $('<br />'),                                    
            $('<input />', { id: values[i], type: 'button', value: 'Submit',  click: function(){
                // attaching the function to the button
                testAjax(this.id);  // Calling the function below.                                                  
            }}),
            endDiv // Ending the div         
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `jQuery` *creates* the HTML element `div` when appending `<div id='appm'>`, and that *includes* the closing tag. So, the notation `$('<form />')`, for example, results the same as `$('<form>')`.

To achive what you want, you can do just what you are already doing by utilizing another nested `.append`:

```
$('<form>', { id: values[i], method: 'POST' }).append(
    $('<div>', { id: 'appm' }).append(
        $('<textarea>', { id: "teast", name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', value: values[i], type: 'text' }),
        $('<br>'),
        // [...] 
        $('<br>'),                                    
        $('<input>', { id: values[i], type: 'button', value: 'Submit',  click: function(){ testAjax(this.id); } })
    )
)
```

Comment: I would, but it requires 15rep :( I marked it as an answer, does that give you points tho?